# Airflow - can't authenticate when opening spreadsheet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I'm trying to connect to a spreadsheet, and read the cells with Airflow so I can eventually add this to a database. For now I've created a Google Sheets document, and have authenticated via the Google Client in my browser, however when I run the code it results in the following error: ""User must be authenticated when user project is provided".

```
Details: "\[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 
'reason': 'USER_PROJECT_DENIED',
'domain': 'googleapis.com', 
'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 
'consumer': 'projects/User-2023-01-19'}}\]"\>
```

Here's the code I'm running after running and authenticating via " gcloud auth application-default login"

```
from airflow.providers.google.suite.hooks.sheets import GSheetsHook
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def get_data_from_spreadsheet():
    hook = GSheetsHook(
    )
    spreadsheet = hook.get_values('-Sheets key-','B3' )
get_data_from_spreadsheet()
```

I've tried running the code block above, expecting to get the data posted in the sheet, and instead get an error.

Comment: did you create the connection `google_cloud_default`?

Comment: I think I did via the console

Comment: You can verify that by making a [call to the Airflow API listing the connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_connections) (or check in the UI). Maybe the [docs on connecting to google cloud](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html) can help too.

Comment: Thanks a lot TJaniF, I'll try this again later today